# following code of string concatenation behaving unusual,whats the reason?

Tags: c, string

1. code 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char Str1[100], Str2[100];
    int i, j;
    printf("\n Please Enter the First String :  ");
    gets(Str1);
    printf("\n Please Enter the Second String :  ");
    gets(Str2);
    for (i = 0; Str1[i]!='\0'; i++);    
   {                                }
    for (j = 0; Str2[j]!='\0'; j++, i++)
    {
        Str1[i] = Str2[j];
    }
    Str1[i] = '\0';
    printf("\n String after the Concatenation = %s", Str1);
    return 0;
}
```

while writing the code by mistake I placed closing braces of 1st for loop after 2nd for loop though the code working fine and giving the output same as first code.

2. code 2

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{char Str1[100], Str2[100];
    int i, j;
    printf("\n Please Enter the First String :  ");
    gets(Str1);
    printf("\n Please Enter the Second String :  ");
    gets(Str2);
    for (i = 0; Str1[i]!='\0'; i++);    
   {
    for (j = 0; Str2[j]!='\0'; j++, i++)
    {
        Str1[i] = Str2[j];
    }
    Str1[i] = '\0';
    }
    printf("\n String after the Concatenation = %s", Str1);
    return 0;
}
```

so what's reason second code is giving same as first ,in my opinion str1 value should be replaced but its not. Rather it appends the value str2 in str1.
Can anyone explain the reason behind it?

- [output of first code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLvCd.jpg)
- [output of second code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ki5T4.jpg)

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: Don't use `gets`.  It's been deprecated, and IIRC, it has been removed from the latest versions of C and C++.

Comment: Because you have a semicolon after first `for`. The braces you put afterwards are irrelevant.

Comment: `for (i = 0; Str1[i]!='\0'; i++); { }` and `for (i = 0; Str1[i]!='\0'; i++) {}` are equivalent. Both are executing empty body, searching for an element with value `'\0'` from the array `Str1`. The first code has empty block, which also does nothing, *after* the `for` loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "str1 value should be replaced"? What is the expected output for `Str1 = "apple"` and `Str2 = "tree"`?

Comment: @MikeCAT okay ,thanks

Comment: after executing it should be Str1=tree right, if semicolon was not place after first for for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just summarizing what has been said in comments...

Due to the `;` after the for loop, this:

```
for (i = 0; Str1[i]!='\0'; i++);
```

Is equivalent to

```
for (i = 0; Str1[i]!='\0'; i++);    
{                                }
```

If you add a `;` directly after the loop, then the loop has an empty body.
Further,

```
some block of code
```

is equivalent to

```
{
    some block of code
}
```

if we put accessing variables declared in `some block of code` after that block and similar issues (that do not apply here) aside.

Hence, removing the `{}` and surrounding the following block of code in braces, does not change the meaning of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the '}' after the first for loop as it is ending the loop without any executing anything because you don't have anything in between {}. So put the '}' symbol after the end of secand for loop.